# Python Requests library throws exceptions in logging

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-requests, urllib3

The Python `requests` library appears to have some rather strange quirks when it comes to its logging behaviour.
Using the latest Python 2.7.8, I have the following code:

```
import requests
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    filename='mylog.txt',
    format='%(asctime)-19.19s|%(task)-36s|%(levelname)s:%(name)s: %(message)s',
    level=eval('logging.%s' % 'DEBUG'))

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.info('myprogram starting up...', extra={'task': ''})     # so far so good
...
(ommited code)
...
payload = {'id': 'abc', 'status': 'ok'}

# At this point the program continues but throws an exception.
requests.get('http://localhost:9100/notify', params=payload) 

print 'Task is complete! NotifyURL was hit! - Exiting'
```

My program seems to exit normally, however inside the log file it creates (mylog.txt) I always find the following exception:

```
KeyError: 'task'
Logged from file connectionpool.py, line 362
```

If I remove this:
`requests.get('http://localhost:9100/notify', params=payload)`
then the exception is gone.

What exactly am I doing wrong here and how may I fix this?
I am using requests v2.4.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in [t-8ch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2002093/t-8ch)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26787568/2642204), the logger is being used internally by the `requests` library and this library doesn't know anything about your parameters. A possible solution is to implant a [custom filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#filter-objects) in the library's logger (in this case, one of its modules):

```
class TaskAddingFilter(logging.Filter):
    def __init__(self):
        logging.Filter.__init__(self)

    def filter(self, record):
        record.args = record.args + ('task', '')

# ...

requestsLogger = logging.getLogger('requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool')
requestsLogger.addFilter(TaskAddingFilter())
```

Potentially, you need to add such filtering to all loggers from `requests`, which are:

- `requests.packages.urllib3.util`
- `requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool`
- `requests.packages`
- `requests.packages.urllib3`
- `requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry`
- `requests`
- `requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager`

in my version, you can find them using the `logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict` attribute. So, you could do something like this:

```
for name,logger in logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.iteritems():
    logger = logging.getLogger(name) # because of lazy initialization
    if name.startswith('requests.'):
        logger.addFilter(TaskAddingFilter())
```

The `TaskAddingFilter` can be a bit smarter of course, e.g. adding a particular `task` entry depending on where you are in your code. I've added only the simplest solution for the code you've provided - the exception doesn't occur anymore - but the wide range of possibilities seems obvious ;)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your custom logging format, where you expect a `%(task)`.
Requests (or rather the bundled urllib3) does not include the `task` parameter when logging, as it has no way of knowing, that you expect this.

Comment: OK. I get that. Now, how may I fix this? Is there a way to make `Requests` aware of my `task` parameter?

Comment: You are using request in a synchronous way, so just log manually after checking the requests return value instead of using a custom format.